# How to find if an array has a random number [Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)] or not in it in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to create a hangman game in html,css,js.
So i am now to give it a randomisation on based how the question will be displayed -

> Create the Random number - Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)

> First of all check if the array(this array contains which questions are already done) has the random number

| if not | if yes |
| --- | --- |
| *then allow the below statement to happen* | then let the function run again and agiin until random number is not there in th array |

> First question based on the random number and second olso and so on

But actually i cannot figure out how to check in the array has the random number. I tried:-

this works

```
function NextQuestion() {
  let done = ['1','2'];
  let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  let include = done.includes('1');  
  if (include == true) {
    alert('true');// this works
  }
}
```

this doesn't

```
function NextQuestion() {
  let done = ['1','2'];
  let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  let include = done.includes(random);  
  if (include == true) {
    alert('true');// this does not works
  }
}
```

The difference is that in the first one it has **includes('1');** but in second it has **includes(random);**

***Do you know why this happens if you do please let me know and please give the solution to this problem***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Random is a number and your array contains strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will explain why

```js
let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
console.log(random) 
console.log(
  ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].includes(random)
);  

console.log(
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].includes(random)
);
```

So your hangman will work if you store the random as they are created

Answer (score 1):

@mplungian correctly answered the question you raised in your title. But I believe you are going the wrong way about it if want to ask a given number of questions in a random sequence. For this you should simply step through the questions array with a for loop. But before you do that the array should be shuffled:

```js
function shfl(a){
 // Durstenfeld shuffle:
 for(let i=a.length;i>1;){
 j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
 if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}
const q=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
shfl(q);
q.forEach((n,i)=>console.log(i+1+". Q"+n));
```